# How to measure length of multiple arcs and lines in SolidWorks?

Tags: solidworks

I'm using SolidWorks 2023 and I have a curve like this one:

[image]

And I want to find it's full length. I've already tried to do it with Measure tool, but it doesn't show the length to me. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found out that I can just Ctrl-Click every segment and the total length will appear in the bottom-right corner.